# Why was my question likely to be closed as subjective?

Tags: support

I was going to ask a question but a blue box popped up saying that it would probably be closed for being subjective. What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably used some certain triggerwords in your title or body - one common one is 'what is the best...' or 'what is your favorite...'

If you post the question text here, we can give you a more certain answer. It's just the system warning you that it *thinks* you might be asking an opinion based question.